# Why does my computer (quad core, 4gb ram) slow to a grinding halt when ubuntuone is syncing

Tags: ubuntu-one

Why does my computer (quad core, 4gb ram) slow to a grinding halt when ubuntuone is syncing!!! I'm on 11.04 and getting really fed up with it... I can't do anything when it syncs!

Comment: Easy solution: install Dropbox, and uninstall Ubuntu One. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the initial sync and you have many thousands of files, there is a [known bug in Ubuntu One which causes high CPU usage](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/407762). It should, after a while, drop to normal levels.

However, if you stop it before it's finished, it will start again.

A good page for issues with Ubuntu One is the [Bugs Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Bugs) which answers most problems.

Comment: It seems to do it after a while and I only have about 500 files in my sync folder